# Apply the active MSR filters on camera frame

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, image-enhancement

I use OpenCV for detect eyes in my project and I intend to use Catalano library for use MultiScaleRetinex(for illumination enhancement) but there is problem when I passed camera frame to library, the library just accepted bitmap parameters and I don't know what to do...

Any help will be appreciated

PS:I attache screen shot

[screen shot android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV1RQ.jpg)

Comment: You need to convert opencv Mat to a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Hi everybody or nobody I solve this with:

```
Bitmap b21 =  Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, b21);
```